# Groovy Apache Commons CSV printHeaders - unable to cast input to ResultSet

Tags: groovy, apache-commons-csv

My Groovy code to read from a database table and write to a CSV file is working -

```
Sql dbConnection = Sql.newInstance(dbConnectionParameters)

new FileWriter("items.csv").withWriter { writer ->

    CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.RFC4180)

    List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") 

    println "there are ${resultSet.size()} items in the item table"

    resultSet.each {row ->
        printer.printRecord(row.values())
    }
}
```

But I'm trying to add a header to my CSV file containing the column names from the database table.  And Commons CSV provides a printHeaders() method and the Groovy rows() method provides a closure that understands query result metadata (column names, etc).

But when I try this -

```
Sql dbConnection = Sql.newInstance(dbConnectionParameters)

new FileWriter("items.csv").withWriter { writer ->

    CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)

    List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") { meta ->
        printer.printHeaders(meta as ResultSet)
    }

    println "there are ${resultSet.size()} items in the item table"

    resultSet.each {row ->
        printer.printRecord(row.values())
    }
}
```

I get a MissingMethodException and looking for some help to understand how I might handle this.

Here's the exception -

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.VDBJDBCResultSetMetaData.getMetaData() is
> applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
> getMetaClass() groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of
> method:
> com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.VDBJDBCResultSetMetaData.getMetaData() is
> applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
> getMetaClass()

My (lame?) analysis - printHeaders() accepts a java.sql.ResultSet class as an argument and I'm providing a VDBJDBCResultSet object.  Some background - I'm using a (required) database driver that extends/implements the java.sql.ResultSet interface, hence the VDBJDBCResultSet object.  I thought that I could cast that VDBJDBCResultSet object to a ResultSet and that would be the right approach for printHeaders() but I'm clearly lost as it doesn't work.  I tried a number of different approaches to achieving that cast but none of them worked.

Initially I tried no cast,

```
List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") { meta ->
    printer.printHeaders(meta)
}
```

Then using Groovy syntax I tried casting meta to a ResultSet,

```
List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") { meta ->
    printer.printHeaders(meta as ResultSet)
}
```

And then in desperation I tried things like,

```
List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") { meta ->
    printer.printHeaders((ResultSet) meta)
}
```

None of them worked and further complicating matters for me, apparently ResultSet has a "parallel" class, ResultSetMetaData, which actually holds the metadata but this parallel aspect seems to be (hopefully?) transparent as I notice that the signature for Commons CSV printHeaders() is `public void printHeaders( java.sql.ResultSet resultSet )` and my assumption is that it completely works and it's the fact that mine is passing a VDBJDBCResultSet that is creating my challenge.  Since printHeaders() accepts a ResultSet that must somehow (magic?) give it access to the ResultSetMetaData.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSVPrinter.printHeaders` requires `ResultSet` as a parameter (not metadata)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#printHeaders-java.sql.ResultSet-

There is another method `CSVPrinter.printRecords(ResultSet resultSet, boolean printHeader)` that could do all work for you

so, we have to find how to get ResultSet from groovy Sql object

the easiest way Sql.query( query, Closure ):

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#query(groovy.lang.GString,groovy.lang.Closure)

the following code should work:

```
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)

dbConnection.query("select * from item limit 5") { rs ->
    printer.printRecords(rs, true)
}
```

unfortunately this does not give you ability to print rows count

also you can extend your code to this:

```
    CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.RFC4180)

    List resultSet = dbConnection.rows("select * from item limit 5") 

    println "there are ${resultSet.size()} items in the item table"
    if(resultSet.size()>0){
        printer.printRecord(resultSet[0].keySet())  //print names from the first row
    }

    resultSet.each {row ->
        printer.printRecord(row.values())
    }
```

Sql.rows() returns list of [GroovyRowResult](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html) and each row is represented like a map where each key-value pair represents column name-value

Comment: Thanks!  This works just like you said.

Learned to pay attention to return types - query() returns a ResultSet and eachRow() returns a GroovyResultSet.  And that the analog of values() is keySet() - I expected keys()... and that printRecords takes an optional parameter... :)  After your explanation I feel like I should have been able to figure it out, thanks again!